# What gets loaded after TableViewDelates and DataSource methods?

Tags: ios

I'm trying to make my TableViewController do some initial setup of the cells. I put my code in DidViewLoad and it worked for setting up the navigation bars (left and right buttons) but I notice it's not the right place to manipulate the cells yet because DidViewLoad gets call before the cells even got created by the delegate methods. Where should I put my code to set up the cell right after everything is done loading?

Comment: What sort of manipulation do you want to do?

Comment: I want to call a method to set textLabel to today's date and keep the row selected, like in the Calendar app on the iphone when you create a new event and you select the Start & End date and on the next screen the Starts row is selected and using a default date.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out. just do inside cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
[tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] animated:NO scrollPosition:0];
```